# Missing File Format option after re-install of Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, file-format

I re-installed Delphi XE 2, but I don't know what I may have done wrong, because now my IDE code editor doesn't have "File Format" options for ANSI, UTF-8, etc anymore. It just has "Text Form" and "Binary Form".

This is how it was before:

[image]

And now:

[image]

Consequently, all files opened are incorrect, because of encoding.

I would like to know, how can I add the File Format options again?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is that dot in the file name on your first picture? There's obviously some difference in what you have opened. Does that happen if you open the same file? Have you installed the same IDE wizards as before?

Comment: Both are same files, I hide the name of the file and that dot is because I forgot to hide.